# How to build the C simulator of rocket chip

Tags: riscv, rocket

I get the following error when build the C simulator:

~/rocket-chip/emulator$ make

make: *** No rule to make target `/home/rocket-chip/emulator/generated-src/Top.DefaultConfig.prm`, needed by `/home/rocket-chip/emulator/generated-src/consts.DefaultConfig.h`.  Stop.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the Rocket Chip `README.md`, you need to update submodules after cloning the repo:

```
cd /home/rocket-chip
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

After this completes, the C emulator should build.  Note that you must have the RISC-V tools installed as well; follow the steps in `README.md` for details.

Comment: Thank you! I installed RISC-V tools last year. Maybe I should update that.